# Insert Emoticons into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert emoticons into my MS SQL.

I uses the following query to insert:

```
Dim command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[emoji]([Message]) VALUES('" & "☺️" & "')", SQLCon)
```

But on my db, it appear as `???????`.

from the comments
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0  (Build 17134: )

How can i save the emoji as it appears to be in DB.

Comment: Column data type? Column collation?

Comment: and what version of SQL Server?

Comment: i am using nvarchar

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 17134: )

Comment: As you can see in both answers: you need to use `N` before a literal string in order to instruct the server that the string is Unicode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
Dim command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[emoji]([Message]) VALUES(N'" & "☺️" & "')", SQLCon)
```

Comment: Personally, I would parametrise this as I suspect the value is coming from user input; and it's never a good idea to inject values in SQL.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly suggest you parametrise your query, don't inject the value. Then, provided you declare your parameter as the correct datatype, this will work fine. So something like:

```
Dim Emojis As String = "☺️"

Dim SQL As String = "Insert into [dbo].[emoji]([Message]) VALUES(@Message);"
Dim command As New SqlCommand(SQL,SQLCon)

command.Parameters.Add("@Message", SqlDbType.NVarChar,100).Value = Emojis 'Guessed Length for the parameter
```

Comment: Of course, the database column data type must also be `nvarchar` to properly store these characters.

Comment: OP had addressed that one in the comments, @DanGuzman : *"i am using nvarchar "*

Comment: Upvoting for "parametrise your query". *This is critical*.

Comment: Would be interesting to hear from the downvote here; what was the reason? What is parametrisation bad or dangerous? If it's because this answer is "longer" i suggest looking up SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
declare @t table (emoji nvarchar(50))

Insert into @t VALUES(N'☺️')


select * from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NVARCHAR` datatype for the column. 
eg.

```
declare @tbl table(message nvarchar(50))
insert into @tbl values(N'')
select * from @tbl
```

and I suggest you must use the SqlParameter to inserting or updating the data in SQL column.